# Controlling color swaps in Gmail in dark mode

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I am having issues with Gmail in dark mode on mobile clients, namely the color choices it uses.

If I specify green `background-color: #00ff00;` as a background color, Gmail in dark mode changes the value to a dark green `background-color: #1c4211;`. It's not my first choice for a dark green. I am looking for ways to customize the color.

I have tried to target Gmail specifically with a class like: `u ~ div td background-color: #00ff00;`. With some color choices like red, it adheres to the color choice. In many others, it makes a substitution for a darker color that doesn't work for my intended needs.

Has anyone run across a solution to fine-tune the swap process?

Comment: There is none for Gmail atm but you can find CSS on how to target other email clients here: https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers

Comment: Thank you, @Syfer. Apple/IOS isn't a problem and Outlook currently will inline color values with `!important`which makes it impossible to override. My current plan is to get a job with the gmail team, secretly  add an exploit. Wish me luck.

Answer (score 8):

For gmail app on iphone I've found that hsl colors with multiple gradients do the trick, like so:

```
background: #10c893;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  hsl(163,85%,42%) 0%, hsl(163,85%,42%) 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  hsl(163,85%,42%) 0%,hsl(163,85%,42%) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  hsl(163,85%,42%) 0%,hsl(163,85%,42%) 100%);
```

Comment: I was stuck for 1 week already and you are a GOD SEND. in my case I use mjml and use the <mj-style inline="inline"> to appy this to any div that I do not want to invert at dark mode. cheers. I hate this email template thingy

Answer (score 2):

Messing with the answer from @Iggy, I found that hsl colors aren't necessary, and with `linear-gradient` now [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#browser_compatibility), we can specify the background color more simply like this:

```
background: #fff;
background: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
```

I tested this in both Android and iOS Gmail apps on [litmus.com](https://www.litmus.com/).

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution we used was to create a 1px gif and use it as the background image for the containers we wanted to force to be a certain color.

```
<td style="background-image: url('https://path-to-image-here/pixel-ffffff.gif'); background-repeat:repeat;">
                    <div>
                        THIS HAS A WHITE BACKGROUND IN DARK MODE NOW!
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Only thing we haven't figured out yet is how to force the font colors not to invert. Thinking we will alter our design a bit and use grays instead of black with the hope gmail won't invert it.