HTML email, CSS gets inverted when in dark-mode on iOS Gmail
I have an HTML email that I'm sending from a nodejs app, but when the email is viewed on Gmail on iOS, all the elements that had background-color or color property they get reversed. So most obvious is on black/white elements. I saw few guides and articles trying to address this issue up but nothing helped.
I tried adding these meta tags:
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light">
<meta name="supported-color-schemes" content="light">

Outlook on iOS respects them, Gmail on iOS doesn't.
I also tried to overwrite it by this media tag:
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark ) {
#header {
background-color: black!important;
height: 60px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
/* padding: 17px; */
 }
 #headerLink{
  color: white!important;
}
}


Unfortunately Gmail doesn't support the media query you attempted to do.
See this table
However, CSS blend modes are now supported in Gmail, and you can use them for these purposes. I found this article online with a very novel approach.
Basically, it uses screen and difference blend modes so that when Gmail inverts the colors, it subtracts the values of those colors and blends them into, basically, the original color. The article also provides a way of only targeting Gmail to avoid issues with other email providers, with a simple selector trick:
"Gmail replaces the doctype of an email with a <u> element." So you can use the next sibling combinator + to target whatever element you need (worth noting you need to add a class to your <body>).
u + .body .yourElement{ mix-blend-mode: difference; }
Unless you use a <u> element somewhere else (which is pretty rare given modern practices), this will work just fine for you. Furthermore, blend modes have good browser support (96%+) nowadays.
Hope it helps you!

I saw this article earlier and I tried whatever they are suggesting, actually it's not saying directly mix-blend-mode:difference, it requires first screen on a parent div, then difference on wherever the text is. I solved the background colours by linear-gradient(), https://stackoverflow.com/a/67443053/9102884 this answer helped. But for text colour I still haven't figured out.
